# Create table as in Redshift defining primary key

Tags: primary-key, amazon-redshift

I am trying to replicate a table using CTAS clause in redshift by additionally specifying a primary key to the table.

Tried below syntax but no luck. However, I was able to specify DISTKEY/SORTKEY using the same syntax

```
create table date_dim
PRIMARY KEY(date_key)
--DISTKEY ( date_key )
as
   select date_key,
   calendar_date,.....;
```

I want to use primary key as part of merge logic I am designing in my flow.

TIA!

Answer (score 4):

Many people consider primary and foreign keys in Redshift to be an anti-pattern (because they're unenforced), but my team built a small tool (a Python script) that supports this scenario.

You write your `select` statement in a normal SQL file, define primary key, foreign keys, distkey, etc in a YAML configuration file, and then use the script to generate (and optionally execute) SQL to create and populate the table.

We also include an [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) operator to make it simple to schedule and automate this.

The repo is [here](https://github.com/Ro-Data/Ro-Create-Table-From-Select), and we wrote a bit more about it [on our team blog](https://medium.com/ro-data-team-blog/create-a-redshift-table-directly-from-a-select-statement-5f695486e367)

Answer (score 2):

You can only specify **distkey** and **sortkey** in CTAS . Here is the below link which describes what all options you can specify 
[Redshift CTAS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_AS.html)

Answer (score 1):

If the column you are wishing to dub as primary key is already non-nullable you can use this:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> ADD CONSTRAINT <a_name_for_this_constraint> PRIMARY KEY (<attribute_name>)
```

e.g.: `ALTER TABLE member ADD CONSTRAINT pk_1 PRIMARY KEY (member_id);`

Answer (score -3):

Redshift doesn't support primary and foreign key constraints: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Defining_constraints.html

Comment: how do I write Merge queries then!

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do but hopefully the documentation on updating and inserting new data should have examples of merge logic that are relevant for you: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_updating-inserting-using-staging-tables-.html

Comment: _enforce_ and _support_ do not mean the same thing. I would like my ERD's to have PK's, please.